# How to get redirector.googlevideo.com link from a Google drive video

Tags: php, google-drive-api, streaming, playback

I have a google drive video file (like https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view) and I want to get its redirector.googlevideo.com link.

How do sites like http://api.getlinkdrive.com/ do it? I've tried using the Google Drive REST API, (both v2 and v3) but still can't find a way to do it. Many tv-show and movie sites host their content on google drive, and use this "cloaked" URL that expires so you can't for example embed it somewhere else.

The closest I've gotten is by going to docs.google.com/get_video_info?docid=FILE_ID and getting the fmt_stream_map links, but that doesn't return the redirector link which I need.

Comment: please include code

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo, but that's not what I am asking, please re-read the question.

Comment: @MiheretabAlemu There is no code needed to be shown, I am asking how to retrieve the redirector.googlevideo.com link from a google drive video.

Comment: Found this [forum](https://support.joomlatools.com/forums/topic/3743-googledrive-hide-original-url-for-remote-link) which suggested to create a direct link for the document stored on Google Drive. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/) which explains how to create a direct link for a file hosted in Google Drive and a [tool](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/) which can automatically create the direct links for you. You may also check on this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/ZJCw1u29KwU) which might help.

Comment: @abielita Thank you, but it's not what I'm looking for like I mentioned in my question. The whole purpose is to hide the original drive file ID, and to provide a redirector.googlevideo.com link specifically, like many video-streaming sites such as kissanime.to do.

Answer (score 4):

Php code will not work here and even meaningless, because it will return the result for server side.

This is my Javascript/Ajax code.
Unfortunately, you should use [Access-Control-Allow-Origin extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) in Chrome browser.
First, please see [this screenshot](http://prntscr.com/fyqceq) of console window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/YOUR-JW-PLAYER-LICENSE-KEY.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <p id="urls"></p>
      <div id="myElement"></div>
   </body>

   <script>
      var docid = "0B4Mn0g4wWmQ1ZThycVhOcDJQc2c";
      var api_url = "https://docs.google.com/get_video_info";
      var ans = {};
      var url = "";

      getGoogleVideoUrl();

      function getGoogleVideoUrl(){
        $.ajax({
          url: api_url,
          type: "get",
          data: { 
            docid: docid,
          },
          success: function(response) {
            //
            // get value of which key is 'fmt_stream_map'.
            //
            var fmt_stream_map = getQueryVariable(response, 'fmt_stream_map');
            //
            // split my comma
            //
            var maps = fmt_stream_map.split("%2C");
            //
            // loop all links, 
            //  
            var purl = "";          
            for (x in maps) {
                var res = decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(maps[x])).split('|');
                // purl = res[1].replace(new RegExp("/\/[^\/]+\.google\.com/", 'g'),"//redirector.googlevideo.com/");
                // purl = res[1].replace(new RegExp("\.google\.com/", 'g'),".googlevideo.com/");

                purl = res[1];
                //.replace(/.c.docs.google.com/g,".googlevideo.com")
                //.replace(/app=explorer/g,"app=storage")
                //.replace(/key=ck2/g,"key=cms1")
                //.replace(/&cp=/g,"&api=")
                //.replace(/,cp&/g,',api&')
                //.replace(/,cp,/g,',api,')
                //.replace(/=cp,/g,'=api,')
                //.replace(/&sparams=/g,'&cms_redirect=yes&sparams=');

                switch (parseInt(res[0])) {
                case 5:
                    quality = 'Low Quality, 240p, FLV, 400x240';
                    break;
                case 17:
                    quality = 'Low Quality, 144p, 3GP, 0x0';
                    break;
                case 18:
                    quality = 'Medium Quality, 360p, MP4, 480x360';
                    break;
                case 22:
                    quality = 'High Quality, 720p, MP4, 1280x720';
                    break;
                case 34:
                    quality = 'Medium Quality, 360p, FLV, 640x360';
                    break;
                case 35:
                    quality = 'Standard Definition, 480p, FLV, 854x480';
                    break;
                case 36:
                    quality = 'Low Quality, 240p, 3GP, 0x0';
                    break;
                case 37:
                    quality = 'Full High Quality, 1080p, MP4, 1920x1080';
                    break;
                case 38:
                    quality = 'Original Definition, MP4, 4096x3072';
                    break;
                case 43:
                    quality = 'Medium Quality, 360p, WebM, 640x360';
                    break;
                case 44:
                    quality = 'Standard Definition, 480p, WebM, 854x480';
                    break;
                case 45:
                    quality = 'High Quality, 720p, WebM, 1280x720';
                    break;
                case 46:
                    quality = 'Full High Quality, 1080p, WebM, 1280x720';
                    break;
                case 82:
                    quality = 'Medium Quality 3D, 360p, MP4, 640x360';
                    break;
                case 84:
                    quality = 'High Quality 3D, 720p, MP4, 1280x720';
                    break;
                case 102:
                    quality = 'Medium Quality 3D, 360p, WebM, 640x360';
                    break;
                case 104:
                    quality =  'High Quality 3D, 720p, WebM, 1280x720';
                    break;
                default:
                    quality =  'transcoded (unknown) quality';
                    break;
                }
                ans[quality] = purl;
            }
             console.log(ans);
             $('#urls').html(JSON.stringify(ans));

             url  = ans[Object.keys(ans)[0]];
             build_player();

          },
          error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
          }
        });
      }



      function build_player(){
        var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
        playerInstance.setup({
            file: url,
            type: "mp4",
            width: 800 , 
            height: 600,
        }); 
      }

      function getQueryVariable(query, variable) {
          var vars = query.split('&');
          for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
              var pair = vars[i].split('=');
              if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
                  //return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
                  return pair[1];
              }
          }
          console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
          return "";
      }

   </script>
</html>
```

This code works basically, but doesn't play in jwplayer component.

However, if you enter this URL, "https://docs.google.com/get_video_info?docid=0B4Mn0g4wWmQ1ZThycVhOcDJQc2c", directly in chrome browser, get JSON file , parse it manually, use one of URLs directly in this code as jwplayer's file url, it works perfectly, although it contains "app=explorer" tag in itself.

I'm not sure why this happens.
So I tried to compare 2 links and some parameters is different. The first one is from above code and not working, the 2nd JSON file directly and working.)

```
ei=hJ5yWaHCKYXb-wWona2YBA
ei=KZ5yWZSkK4aFqgXAwpoo

susci=o-AC34EOoA1Wst0Heh0U_bP9epqR8K9s4UBhwlqmsxKZKwAOA
susci=o-AH82qbGL8BcWQ3BPybbvZyuNBiDd2Uasz4J0ZNXJCZwobPje

expire=1500698308
expire=1500698217

cp=QVNFUkdfV1NOSVhOOnhwOWFybUloWXNX
cp=QVNFUkdfV1JPSFhOOmpURGRUeUt3eVpv

signature=3D306FD9D9ADA683D313AABDFE057B608A6F2A39.8BB3A9C321B6BEAC8D1D5AEED2F25511DF97CE2B
signature=2C2465BDFC4D9CCFD0D4A42F38BAEF44D55AFDF1.A916937113445ABB90D18B3AE89600729CFADDE6
```

Why first one is not working while 2nd is working?
Any idea of this?

Comment: May be you logged in with your google account in browser @Lin

Answer (score 1):

He is talking about getting the URL from google drive all qualities in 360p,480p,720p,1080p and convert just before the /videoplayback to redirector.googlevideo.com and make it as video/mp4 to do playback in JW Player.I have the full script but it has got a minor problem it says forbidden 403 and it is because of changes google made in API.Have a look at the codes in PHP and let me know if someone can fix it,i will post full script later.

```
function Drive($link) {
    $url = urldecode($link);
    $get = curl1($url);
    $data = explode(',["fmt_stream_map","', $get);
    $data = explode('"]', $data[1]);
    $data = str_replace(array('\u003d', '\u0026'), array('=', '&'), $data[0]);
    $data = explode(',', $data);
    asort($data);
    foreach($data as $list) {
        $data2 = explode('|', $list);
        if($data2[0] == 37) {$q1080p = preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+\.google\.com/","/redirector.googlevideo.com",$data2[1]);}    // 1080P
        if($data2[0] == 22) {$q720p = preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+\.google\.com/","/redirector.googlevideo.com",$data2[1]);}     // 720P
        if($data2[0] == 59) {$q480p = preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+\.google\.com/","/redirector.googlevideo.com",$data2[1]);}     // 480P
        if($data2[0] == 18) {$q360p = preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+\.google\.com/","/redirector.googlevideo.com",$data2[1]);}     // 360P
    }
    $js[0][0] = "$q1080p";
    $js[0][1] = "$q720p";
    $js[0][2] = "$q480p";
    $js[0][3] = "$q360p";
    $js[1][0] = "1080P";
    $js[1][1] = "720P";
    $js[1][2] = "480P";
    $js[1][3] = "360P";
    return $js;     
}
if ($jw[0][0] != "") {
    echo('{file: "'.urldecode($jw[0][0]).'",type: "video/mp4",label: "'.urldecode($jw[1][0]).'"},');
}
if ($jw[0][1] != "") {
    echo('{file: "'.urldecode($jw[0][1]).'",type: "video/mp4",label: "'.urldecode($jw[1][1]).'"},');
}   
if ($jw[0][2] != "") {
    echo('{file: "'.urldecode($jw[0][2]).'",type: "video/mp4",label: "'.urldecode($jw[1][2]).'"},');
}   
if ($jw[0][3] != "") {
    echo('{file: "'.urldecode($jw[0][3]).'",type: "video/mp4",label: "'.urldecode($jw[1][3]).'"},');
}
```

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: @monster1777 Yes i fixed it with blogspot api

Demo is here
https://cdn.123movie.cc/

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a better algorithm from the previous answer.

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $return);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

function Drive($id) {
    $o = [];
    $url = "https://docs.google.com/get_video_info?docid=$id";
    $get = curl($url);

    parse_str($get, $out);
    $data = explode(",", $out["fmt_stream_map"]);

    foreach($data as $d) {
        switch ((int)substr($d, 0, 2)) {
            case 18:
                $r = "360P";
                break;
            case 22:
                $r = "720P";
                break;
            case 37:
                $r = "1080P";
                break;
            case 59:
                $r = "480P";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        $o[$r] = substr(preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+\.google\.com/","/redirector.googlevideo.com", $d), 3);
    }
    ksort($o);
    return $o;
}
$jw = Drive(FILE_ID_HERE);

foreach ($jw as $k => $r) {
    echo json_encode(array("file"=> $r, "type"=> "video/mp4", "label"=> $k))."\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice! anyway, all I'm getting are 403 errors. Do you know why?

Comment: I think Google uses a special mechanism to detect wheather it is a valid request. For now, I use the direct link only, although it links to the source file instead of providing different alternate resolutions.

Comment: Great! Let me check and update with feedback soon. Thanks.

Comment: It was perfect almost and thank you again.
However, the most important thing is just not to use CURL, because google redirect link will contain the requested IP address.
In your case, the requested IP is host IP, instead of client IP, so need to use other methods something like client side Ajax call. (CURL is for server-side.)And in case of using ajax call, just take care of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", since google doesn't allow to refer itself using Ajax.
And also it seems that some minor parts should be changed.
I think you'd like to test one link you got in your side at least.
Best.

Comment: @GertHeine any idea how to "take care" of CORS?

Comment: @Yagiz Simply, you can use this chrome extension. [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).
Well, I got proper link by above code, but it was by replacing some strings, such link "redirector.google.com....". However, anyway to get a style of "*******.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/?....." directly?

Comment: @GertHeine I think removing the preg_replace function will help. CORS was one big obstacle in this project, and if anyone is curious, I will be glad to post my alternative source code on GitHub for reference.

Comment: @bckps7336 I'm sure it will never work by replacing some strings. instead, we'd like to get the link directly without any change of the link. And also it will contain "&app=storage" as GET Parameter, (now it returns just "&app=explorer", but the style of link will not work. Best.

Comment: @GertHeine I think Google's player has a very complicated background api that may be occasionally obfuscated and hard to crack. I tried this method about half a year ago and it worked, but maybe Google realized it somehow.

Comment: @bckps7336 where did you find the API for using "get_video_info", it dosen't seem to be in the Google Drive API or the Youtube API.